# Jenkins shell not assuming two variables

Tags: jenkins

I'm building a jenkins job where depending on a choice parameter ($APP) it will use pref variable and "attach" to the host name

The hostname will be used in ansible playbook to deploy the applicaion and use  --limit to point the host we define in the choice parameter I defined as HOST1

```
case $APP in
  "app01")
      PREF=WS-APP01;;
  "app02")
      PREF=WS-APP02;;
  "app03")
      PREF=WS-app03;;
   *)
      exit 2;;
  
esac


H2=""
H3=""



if ! [ -z $HOSTS3 ]
then
    H3="$PREF_${HOSTS3}*:"
fi
if ! [ -z $HOSTS2 ]
then
  H2="$PREF_${HOSTS2}*:"
fi

HOSTS="$PREF_${HOSTS1}*:$H2:$H3"

echo $PREF_$HOSTS1
```

Up until here seems quite simple and self explanatory.

But when I run to test the echo, it only returns the host foun in $HOSTS1

```
10:28:58 + case $APP in
10:28:58 + PREF=APP01
10:28:58 + H2=
10:28:58 + H3=
10:28:58 + '[' -z ']'
10:28:58 + '[' -z ']'
10:28:58 + HOSTS='qaaciapp00001v*::'
10:28:58 + echo qaaciapp00001v
```

Tried to google this behavior but no success finding an explanation.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you executing this shell script? Within the Jenkins Pipeline? Can you add how you are executing it?

Comment: No, not a pipeline. It's an independent build job.
where in the build section I add an execution shell and in there I add shell script with the predefined choice parameters. One of them, the host.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following for the echo.

```
echo "$PREF_$HOSTS1"
```

or

```
echo "\$PREF_$HOSTS1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets... Brackets saved the day...

```
case $APP in
  "app01")
      PREF=WS-APP01;;
  "app02")
      PREF=WS-APP02;;
  "app03")
      PREF=WS-app03;;
   *)
      exit 2;;
  
esac


H2=""
H3=""



if ! [ -z $HOSTS3 ]
then
    H3="${PREF}_${HOSTS3}*:"
fi
if ! [ -z $HOSTS2 ]
then
  H2="${PREF}_${HOSTS2}:"
fi

HOSTS="${PREF}_${HOSTS1}:$H2:$H3"

echo ${PREF}_${HOSTS1}
```

Thank you very much for you assistance ycr